# How to find the inverse function of $f(n) = n \ log_2(n)$

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

Is there a way to rearrange such a function to a form like $n = \text{something}$ ?

Comment: As Siong Thye Goh answered, the only explicit solution is Lambert function. Otherwise, numerical methods would work very efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

If $m = n \log_2 n$

then $m\ln 2 = n\ln n$

[Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) is the inverse of $g(a)=a \exp(a)$, that is

$$W(a \exp(a))=a$$
and hence by letting $a=\ln n$,
$$W(n\ln n ) = \ln n$$

Hence from $m \ln 2 = n \ln n$, by taking the lambert W-function,

$$W(m \ln 2) = W(n \ln n)= \ln n$$

Hence $$n = \exp(W(m \ln 2))$$

Remark: If you are alright with a numerical algorithm, bisection should work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it's apparent to me that the answer is too far over my head to be useful to me right now, but at least I know there's an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a form that looks interesting. For $m=n\log_2n>4$, we have

$$n=\frac{m}{\log_2n}=\frac{m}{\log_2\frac{m}{\log_2n}}=\cdots
=\frac{m}{\log_2\frac{m}{\log_2\frac{m}{\log_2\cdots}}}.$$

Looks like a continued fraction. But it's continued logarithm. Not sure if it's useful though.

Comment: I'm no mathematician so this could be a trivial constraint to satisfy, but having n on the right of the equation isn't helpful is it? Or is there some way to convert the continued fraction to some expression only containing $m$ as a parameter?

Comment: If the substitution is done infinitely many times, the right-hand side has only $m$. So it's an explicit formula for $n$, though not a "closed-form" (depending on what it means).

Answer (score 1):

$$y=n \log_2 n = \frac{ n \ln n }{\ln 2}$$

$$y \ln 2 = n \ln n$$

Now, let $n=e^m$

$$y \ln 2 = me^m$$

$$y \ln 2 = W(m)$$

Where $W(m)$ is Lambert W Function.

So, finally we've :
$$y = \frac{W(\ln n)}{\ln 2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it's apparent to me that the answer is too far over my head to be useful to me right now, but at least I know there's an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an answer at the level of high school or introductory college algebra, then it suffices to look at the plot of the function.

[image: Plot of f(n) as a function of n]

Here, it is easy to see that the function will not be invertible, as it does not pass the "horizontal line test". More mathematically, this means that, as we need a function to send each number to one AND ONLY ONE other number, if we "flip" this function around the line $y = x$ to see what it's inverse will look like, we see that the point $-0.25$ will get sent to more than one number by the proposed "inverse", which will cause this inverse to not be a function.

If a more sophisticated or partial answer is desired, then the other solutions posted may be better suited towards your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account your comments after answers, let me suppose that, for a given $m$, you want to find numerically the zero of equation
$$f(n)= n \log_2 n-m=\frac{n \log (n)}{\log (2)}-m$$ Newton method will work very well, giving as iterates
$$n_{k+1}=\frac{m \log (2)+n_k}{1+\log (n_k)}$$ Assuming that $m$ is large, you can use the expansion given in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions)
$$W(x)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(x)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$. Using it, you can estimate $n_0$ from $$n=\frac{m \log (2)}{W(m \log (2))}$$

Just for illustration purposes, let us use the above for $m=10^p$. The following table gives the so-generated $n_0$ and the exact solution for six significant figures.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & n_0 & n \\
 1 & 4.62524 & 4.56496 \\
 2 & 22.2676 & 22.3201 \\
 3 & 140.099 & 140.222 \\
 4 & 1002.66 & 1003.00 \\
 5 & 7739.82 & 7740.96 \\
 6 & 62741.7 & 62746.1 \\
 7 & 526153. & 526172. \\
 8 & 4.52298\times 10^6 & 4.52307\times 10^6 \\
 9 & 3.96196\times 10^7 & 3.96201\times 10^7 \\
 10 & 3.52211\times 10^8 & 3.52213\times 10^8 \\
 11 & 3.16844\times 10^9 & 3.16845\times 10^9 \\
 12 & 2.87815\times 10^{10} & 2.87816\times 10^{10}
\end{array}
\right)$$ If you need to polish the solution, Newton method will converge in very few iterations to any level of accuracy. This is shown below for $m=10^{12}$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & n_k \\
 0 & \color{red}{2.87815}16538653414818921185148671484133102881821078\times 10^{10} \\
 1 & \color{red}{2.878159387735}9627781531535908737458118462461822980\times 10^{10} \\
 2 & \color{red}{2.87815938773554852079111735}81957990069957764041854\times 10^{10} \\
 3 & \color{red}{2.8781593877355485207911173570072526567345563696090}\times 10^{10}
\end{array}
\right)$$